# Open certain user in Messenger

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

Is it possible to open certain user by `userId` in Messenger, using `Intent` or Messenger SDK? I have learned [according article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android) but still does not realize how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in facebook `usersId` of friends. The fact is that facebook [generates new ids for users for each app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_610616752452545), and you can't get original `userId` to use it for open Messenger purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an m.me link in the format https://m.me/<username>

Comment: How should I use this? Using `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://m.me/" + facebookUserId))` doesn't work for me

Comment: Using `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.me/" + facebookUserId))` works fine, but may be there is available a special prefix such as `fb:` for Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format: **m.me/{userId}**

Sample URL: **https://m.me/100020321839484**

This id can be taken from user profile: **https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100020321839484**

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes. However I think in an older version it was like an emoji of their face. It did work at getting their profile by putting it in brackets. You can use their ID Number, their name, or URL name to get this. So it would look like [[131318191]]. By clicking their emote you could go to their profile.